# AngularJS: How to pass data outside a succes call in $http.get

Tags: angularjs, json, service, get

In Angular I've made a service to retrieve data with a $http.get call from a json file (in my code: file4.json).
In the success call the data is passed into the array 'bmlService.items'. The console.log shows things went well.
However, this array is empty outside the $http.get function. 
How can I pass the data outside this function?

This is my code:

```
app.service('bmlService', function($http){
var bmlService = {};

bmlService.items = [];

    $http.get("file4.json")

        .success(function(data){
            bmlService.items = data;

            console.log("inside succes call: ", bmlService.items);
            })

        .error(function(data, status){
            alert("Something went wrong...");
        });

        console.log("outside http.get: ", bmlService.items);

return bmlService;
```

});

Comment: You're printing the value **before** it has been assigned by the success callback. The callback is called **asynchronously**, once the http response is available.

Answer (score 0):

> However, this array is empty outside the $http.get function. How can I pass the data outside this function?

You cannot because the AJAX call is asynchronous and this data is available only after the callback has executed - which can happen at a much later stage after firing the AJAX call. So if you want to pass it to the outside you could invoke some other function and pass the data as parameter to this function:

```
.success(function(data) {
    bmlService.passData(data);
})
```

So basically you will have to redesign your code to work with callbacks instead of some sequential calls and variables that get assigned one after the other:

```
var bmlService = {
    passData: function(data) {
        // do something with the data here
    }
};
```

Comment: I disagree. The data is available outside the callback. But only after it has been executed.

Comment: Actually what I meant by it is available only inside the callback is more like the data is available only by the time the callback executes, not before. I will update my answer for more clarity.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov: I don't get it: what should I do with the data as you mentioned in the comment? Should I make a function inside the variable 'bmlService'? Could you please explain this to me?

Comment: Yes, you could make a function that will be called inside the success callback and passed the data parameter. Inside this function you could perform whatever you initially intended to do with the results of the AJAX call.